# Template10 FocusAction to move focus after Enter key?

Tags: winrt-xaml, win-universal-app, template10

Is it possible to use FocusAction to move focus to another control from a KeyBehavior? If so, an example would be helpful. TIA

Comment: I wish I had already thought of this idea. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Fascinating.

This is what does NOT work:

```
<TextBox x:Name="T1">
    <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <b:KeyBehavior Key="Enter">
            <b:FocusAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=T2}" />
        </b:KeyBehavior>
    </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBox>
<TextBox x:Name="T2" />
```

But I love the idea and I will add it to the behavior soon.

In the meanwhile, there is no declarative way to do it without a custom something you create. BTW, I tried this (also does NOT work):

```
<TextBox x:Name="T1">
    <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <b:KeyBehavior Key="Enter">
            <Core:CallMethodAction MethodName="Focus" TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=T2}" />
        </b:KeyBehavior>
    </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBox>
<TextBox x:Name="T2" />
```

Does not work because Focus has parameters and the behavior does not support passing parameters. Though I wish it would.

Great idea though. Sort of like forcing TAB, huh? Cool.

Jerry

Comment: Thanks @Jerry. Glad you like the idea. Would help with form entry scenario in mobile that lacks tab key. I notice there's a pull request for something like this from devinfluencer. I was going to try this in the mean time.